# Rearrangement of packets using pthreads

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, pthreads, fstream

So this is the first time I'm actually asking a question in here, although I have been using this site for ages!

My problem is a bit tricky. I'm trying to develop a client server application for sending large files, using UDP with my own error checking and flow control. Now, I've developed a fully-functioning server and client. Client requests for a specific file, server starts sending. The file is read in parts into a buffer to avoid having to read small bits of the file every time a packet is send, thus saving processing time. Packets consist of 1400 bytes of actual data + a header of 28 bytes (sequence numbers, ack numbers, checksum etc..).

So I had the basics down, a simple stop-and-wait protocol. Send packet and receive ack, before sending next packet.

To be able to implement a smarter flow control algorithm, for starters with just some windowing, I have to run the sending-part and receiving-ack part in two different threads. Now here's where I got into problems. This is my first time working with threads, so please bear with me.

My problem is that the file written from the packets on the client side is corrupt. Well, when testing with a small jpg file, the file is only corrupt 50% of the times, when testing with a MP4 file, it's always corrupt! So I guess maybe the thread somehow rearranges the order in which the packets are send? I use sequence numbers, so the problem must occur before assigning the sequence number to the packets...

I know for sure that the part where I split up the file is correct, and also where I reassemble it on the client side, since I have tested this before trying to implement the threading. It should also be noted that I copied the exact sending-part of the code into the sending-thread, and this also worked perfectly before putting it into a thread.. This is also why I'm just posting the threading-part of my code, since this is clearly what is creating the problem (and since the entire code of the project would take up a loooot of space)

My sending thread code:

```
pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t condition_var = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

static void *send_thread(void *){
if (file.is_open()) {
    while(!file.reachedEnd()){
        pthread_mutex_lock(& mutex);

        if(seq <= upperwindow) {

            int blocksize = file.getNextBlocksize();
            senddata = new unsigned char[blocksize + 28];
            Packet to_send;
            to_send.data = new char[blocksize];
            to_send.sequenceNumber = seq;
            to_send.ackNumber = 0;
            to_send.type = 55; // DATA

            file.readBlock(*to_send.data);
            createPacket(senddata, to_send, blocksize + 28);
            if (server.sendToClient(reinterpret_cast<char*>(senddata), blocksize + 28) == -1)
                perror("sending failed");

            incrementSequenceNumber(seq);

            /* free memory */
            delete [] to_send.data;
            delete [] senddata;

        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(& mutex);
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
} else {
    perror("file opening failed!");
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
}
```

My receiving ack thread code:

```
static void *wait_for_ack_thread(void *){
while(!file.reachedEnd()){
    Packet ack;

    if (server.receiveFromClient(reinterpret_cast<char*>(receivedata), 28) == -1) {
        perror("error receiving ack");
    } else {
        getPacket(receivedata, ack, 28);
        pthread_mutex_lock(& mutex);
        incrementSequenceNumber(upperwindow);

        pthread_mutex_unlock(& mutex)

    }
}
pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

All comments are very much appreciated! :)

EDIT: 
Added code of the readBlock function:

```
void readBlock(char & in){

memcpy(& in, buffer + block_position, blocksize);
block_position = block_position + blocksize;
if(block_position == buffersize){
    buf_position ++;
    if(buf_position == buf_reads){
        buffersize = filesize % buffersize;
    }
    fillBuffer();
    block_position = 0;
}
if(blocksize < MAX_DATA_SIZE){
    reached_end = true;
    return;
}
if((buffersize - block_position) < MAX_DATA_SIZE){
    blocksize = buffersize % blocksize;

}

}
```

Comment: What is the possible point of the mutex in the sending loop, when the *entire* body is latched under it, particularly when *nothing* is done to change the exit condition when (`seq <= upper_window`) evaluates to false? There is no declaration of `senddata`, but I assume it is an `unsigned char*`. This: `file.readBlock(*to_send.data)` looks highly suspicious as well. Without *actual*, ***real*** code it will be sheer speculation what the real issue is.

Comment: why don't you try putting a `std::cout` to print the sequence number of every transaction for send and recieve, so that you can see if the packets are sent in order.

Comment: The mutex just surrounds the if-body, because of the variable upperwindow in the if-condition, which is also being updated in the other thread. I'm not sure however if it is necessary to have?
Yes, the senddata is an unsigned char*. The readBlock function reads a block of data into the char array, and it should be working fine, as it has been tested many times before (without threading), thats why I only posted the threading code..

Comment: @stellarossa I've already tried this, and the sequence numbers seems to get through in order..

Comment: Do you check if received ACK has a proper sequence number? Because if you just send constant "ACK" from client side whenever you get a proper packet you might end up with a duplicated ACK and increment sequence number twice (or more) for the same data. I suggest to use wireshark or tcpdump on both client and server and compare results. Also: what does "to_send.ackNumber" does? It seems to be always set to zero, so.

Comment: Just posted the code for the readBlock function. Changed a tiny bit, and then tested it again, it worked for the MP4 file 2 times with a buffersize large enough to be filled 9 times, third test it failed. Any idea on how it sometimes succeeds and sometimes fails? The size of the file received is the exact amount, so it must have something do to with the arrangement of the data. Oh, and I am checking every packet with a Fletcher 16bit checksum, so it shouldnt be because the packets contains errors...

Comment: I noticed that since I've put the sending and receiving part into two separate threads, the transmission time has more than halfed, which is of course a good thing. But I am wondering if it may influence the file-reading part somehow, maybe the buffer isnt getting completely filled up before I start copy parts of it into the packets?

Answer (score 1):

Create an array that represents the status of the communication.

`0` means unsent, or sent and receiver reported error.  `1` means sending.  `2` means sent, and ack gotten.

Allocate this array, and guard access to it with a mutex.

The sending thread keeps two pointers into the array -- "has been sent up to" and "should sent next".  These are owned by the sending thread.

The ack thread simply gets ack packets, locks the array, and does the transition on the state.

The sending thread locks the array, checks if it can advance the "has been sent up to" pointer (or if it should resend old stuff).  If it notices an error, it reduces the "should be sent next" pointer to point at it.

It then sees if it should send stuff next.  If it should, it marks the node as "being sent", unlocks the array, and sends it.

If the sending thread did no work, and found nothing to do, it goes to sleep on a timeout, and possibly a "kick awake" by the ack thread.

Now, note that the client can get the packets sent by this in the wrong order, unless you limit it to having 1 packet in transit.

The connection status array does not have to be a literal array, but it is easier if you start with that and optimize later.

On the receiving end, you have to pay attention to the sequence number, as the packets can get there out of sequence.  To test this, write a server that sends the packets in the wrong order on purpose, and ensure that the client manages to stitch it together properly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I will definitely try and implement this connections status array, so thanks a lot for that. I was going to implement some sort of data structure anyway to keep track of what has been sent and acked etc., just wanted to get the basic sending/receiving thread running first, since I am new to threads.

Comment: @user1419999 Understood: the problem is your code (A) holds locks for long time, and (B) doesn't transmit the data between the threads that each thread needs.  A count of number of acks is relatively useless if you do not know what is being acked!